# Describe the set of points on the complex plane...

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

Describe the set of points on the complex plane for which $|z-2| + |z+2|=4$...
So, I know you can solve this instantly, just by using definition, but I want to do it the long way..

So,  $$|x- i*y -2|+ |x-i*y +2| = 4$$ 
     $$(x-2)^2 + y^2 + (x+2)^2 +y^2 =16$$
     $$ x^2-4*x+4+y^2+x^2+4*x+ 4 +y^2=16$$

now, $x^2$ and $y^2$ were supposed to eliminate but they don't ...where am I wrong?

Comment: Why would the quadratic terms "supposed" to vanish? That's false...and you squared incorrectly the left hand side.

Comment: What do you mean by "by using definition"?

Comment: I was following the example in my book.It is an engineering book for complex analysis. There's  the example with |x-1| = |x+2| so the quadratic terms eleminate each other...but here they don't.

Comment: $(\lvert z\rvert + \lvert w\rvert)^2 \neq \lvert z\rvert^2 + \lvert w\rvert^2$ in general.

Comment: @Andre It is a degenerate ellipse, right? Just the points on $\mathbb{R}$ between $-2$ and $2$?

Comment: Maybe the interval does not like to be called degenerate. But yes, it can be viewed that way.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't exactly a typo, more like carelessness.

Comment: You are looking, in a Euclidean world, at the triangles with vertices $-2,2,z$ such that the sum of  the lengths of the sides issued from $z$ is equal to the length of the third side. This is satisfied iff $z$ belongs to the third side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course the following is the "wrong" way to do the problem. The geometry, or the Triangle Inequality, tell us that since the distance between $-2$ and $2$ is $4$, our locus consists of all points in the line segment $[-2,2]$.

But we will calculate. If we go to coordinates, we get
$$\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=4.$$
Rewrite as $\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=4-\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}$ and square both sides. There is very nice cancellation, and we get 
$$8x-16=-8\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2},$$
Divide through by $8$, and square both sides again. We get 
$$(x-2)^2=(x-2)^2+y^2.$$
Thus $y=0$.

So all candidates must be on the $x$-axis. We have done some squaring, and extraneous roots may have been introduced. So go back to the original equation, and put $y=0$. We get $|x+2|+|x-2|=4$. It is easy to verify that this is true precisely if $-2\le x\le 2$.

Comment: I love you very much.Thank you.